# How to enable 3D Touch peek & pop but prevent navigation in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I want to enable peek preview en my table View, but i don't want the user to actually navigate to the destination VC. I just want to let him peek, but not navigate into it.

Comment: To allow user to peek, there first has to be something to peek at. So inevitably you will have to create the Destination VC. Then you can use animations plus pop navigation etc to perform your desired effect.

Comment: I have a destination VC which has the preview content, but i don't want the user to navigate to it on Tap, instead, i want to show an Alert

Comment: I haven't implemented this new feature myself from iOS9 before. But can you use segue's and then override `prepareForSegue` to achieve this?

Comment: Yes you can,  the prepareForSegue handles both the peek transition and the pop transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this question.

The VC needs to implement the [UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016569) protocol which handles the peek and pop behaviours.